# Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java. I have created a simple console application

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

When I hit run for the application I get "**Error: Could not find or load main class**"
When I searched for similar issues online, most of them are suggesting to edit , I am not sure what am I supposed to change there in my case

Here is my classpath file.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a `.classpath` file. Right click on `Main.java`, and then select "Run As > Java Application". Of course, you'll need to fix the compiler errors (the red X) that are displayed under the `Main.java` tab in your screen shot. Unfortunately, we can't see those errors. The code posted above

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

is fine, so `Main.java` must have some other code in it.

Comment: I am not running .classpath file, I took that screen shot to show you what I have in .classpath I am running Main.java file only. I have added new screen shot that may help you to understand my question I guess

Comment: Yes I did. Right click on Main.java >> Run As >> 1 Java Application Alt+Shit+x,j and thats when I see "Error: Could not find or load main class "

Comment: Project Clean > Project Build. Because it is running here.

Comment: I went to Project>>Clean and in window select clean all projects and check start build immediately and select Build only selected projects press okay. Now right click on Main.java and click Run as Java Application and I get same error. Is this have to do with work space or anything?

Comment: You cleaned all projects, but only built selected projects? Did you select your project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67348/discussion-between-elliott-frisch-and-habo).